# How to accelerate a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, optimization, vectorization

The following code is for calculating the first order derivative and Hesse of a matrix. I use a lot of `for` loop in the calculation but the speed is not satisfying. I am looking for a method to accelerate the looping speed.

Specifically, we define `f(U,V)=||X-UV||_{F}^{2}`, where `X \in \mathbb{R}^{N \time D}`, `U \in \mathbb{R}^{N \time K}` and `V \in \mathbb{R}^{K \time D}`. And I want to get `d^2f(U_{0},V_{0})`, which is also know as the Hesse matrix.

Actually you do not need to look carefully about the code. I just want to show what it looks like. The problem is with the `for` loops. There are too many of them, leading to a low calculating speed.

Is there a better solution than using a `for`loop?

```
n y=f__(U,V,X,H,W)% U \in N*K, V\in K*D, X \in N*D, H \in D*K
Dim0=size(X);
Dim1=size(U);
N=Dim0(1);%N is the row number of X
D=Dim0(2);%D is the column number of X
K=Dim1(2);%K is the column number of U
% Set Up Matrix Size Parameters
A=zeros(N*K+K*D);

% The diagnal part of H
for k=1:N
    for l=1:K
        %A((k-1)*K+l,(k-1)*K+l)=0;
        for j=1:D
            A((k-1)*K+l,(k-1)*K+l)=A((k-1)*K+l,(k-1)*K+l)+2+2*V(l,j)^2*W(k,j)^2;
        end
    end
end

% The non-diagnal part of H
for k=1:N
    for l=1:K
        for n=1:K
            if(l==n)
                continue;
            end
            %A((k-1)*K+l,(k-1)*K+n)=0;
            for j=1:D
                A((k-1)*K+l,(k-1)*K+n)=A((k-1)*K+l,(k-1)*K+n)+2*V(n,j)*V(l,j)*W(k,j)^2;
            end
        end
    end
end

%The diagnal and non-diagnal part of V
for k=1:K
    for l=1:D
        for m=1:K
            %A(N*K+(k-1)*D+l,N*K+(m-1)*D+l)=0;
            for i=1:N
                A(N*K+(k-1)*D+l,N*K+(m-1)*D+l)=A(N*K+(k-1)*D+l,N*K+(m-1)*D+l)+2*U(i,k)*U(i,m)*W(i,l)^2;
            end
        end
    end
end

%The part of H and V
for k=1:K
    for l=1:D
        for m=1:N
            for n=1:K
                %A(N*K+(k-1)*D+l,(m-1)*K+n)=0;
                if(n==k)
                    A(N*K+(k-1)*D+l,(m-1)*K+n)=(2*V(n,l)*U(m,k)+2*(U(m,:)*V(:,l)-X(m,l)))*W(m,l)^2;
                else
                    A(N*K+(k-1)*D+l,(m-1)*K+n)=2*V(n,l)*U(m,k)*W(m,l)^2;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

%This is a symmatric matrix
for i=N*K+1:N*K+K*D
    for j=1:N*K
        A(i,j)=A(j,i);
    end
end

y=A;
```

Comment: @Adriaan I know I got a lot of bad code...TAT …I tried vectorize before, but I am not sure how to apply that under this circumstance. Could you please give me an example or something? Thanks!

Comment: Since Stack Overflow does not support LaTeX I changed your equations to format them as inline code. Please check whether this is readable in your opinion and if not, change to plain text (so without the LaTeX commands) or make a screenshot of them. I'd prefer plain text, as they are not very relevant for this question.

Comment: Two remarks about the code: you give an equation for `X` and use `X` on the third line, however, you don't input `X` into the function. That won't work. Second, initialise your matrices. You are growing them dynamically (i.e. you add an element each loop iteration) which is terribly slow in MATLAB. If you do something like `A=zeros(size(U))`, or however large it should be, the code will already be much faster. Vectorisation, however does remain the best course of action here.

Comment: Definitely there are too many loops. But the first step is to have something working; something that illustrates the idea properly. In some of your loops you are just overwriting something with new values. How and why would someone vectorize it? Vectorizing is a correct goal you seek, but for that you need to take care of the details first.

Comment: @Adriaan thank you sooooo much!!! It turns out to be 40 times faster! Learned a lot! Do you have any more ideas? :)

Comment: @DanielWong please edit the question to reflect the changes, so I can take a look at what you've done/

Comment: @Adriaan I have just edited my code. FYI. And thanks for the help again! :)